# Can we represent DAG(directed acyclic graph) using PostgreSQL ltree?

Tags: postgresql, directed-acyclic-graphs, ltree

I want to store hierarchical data in the PostgreSQL database.
I found ltree extension but it is used to store tree-structured data i.e there can be only one parent node.
Is there any way I can tweak it to store multiple parent nodes?

Comment: A two-column table of parent_id, child_id can represent it, but will not prevent cycles. Whether that's a useful representation depends on how large the dataset is and what you need to do with it.

Comment: @AdamKG the data will not have cycle and there can be millions of nodes. But, the maximum children for a node can be around 100k.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to do so using the [ltree extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ltree.html), by using two tables: one for your nodes and another for your paths. [Bustawin](https://www.bustawin.com/dags-with-materialized-paths-using-postgres-ltree/) has a great writeup on how to work with DAGs using this extension with this strategy.

For a node to have multiple parents, it is necessary that we define more than one `ltree` path for such node, one that leads from each parent. Say we have a DAG that forms a diamond between nodes A, B, C, and D:

```
A -> B
B -> D
A -> C
C -> D
```

Using the extension, you should have a node D related to two paths, `A.B.D` and `A.C.D`. Both queries should return node D

```sql
SELECT * FROM nodes
JOIN paths ON paths.node_id = nodes.id
WHERE paths.ltree_path ~ "A.B.*{1}"
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM nodes
JOIN paths ON paths.node_id = nodes.id
WHERE paths.ltree_path ~ "A.C.*{1}"
```